# How to call embedded java function in a web page

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

Here is the function that i want to use in a web page and want to call it in script node as other javascript functions. But could you please guide me on how to achieve it.

```
public static String getClipboard() {

    Transferable t = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getContents(null);

    try {
        if (t != null && t.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.stringFlavor)) {
            String text = (String)t.getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
            return text;
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    return null;
}
```

I am completely new to this concept.. If you can answer this question, that will be very helpful..
Thanks

Comment: Do you want to run standar java in the browser? Or am I misinterpreting your question? The browser can only run Javascript.

Comment: Yes, I dont know that we cannot run

Comment: `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getContents(null)` That line alone would require a trusted applet.

Comment: Don't swallow exceptions!  Call `e.printStacktrace()`

Comment: You can not just run Java from a script node. You have to write an applet to run Java code on the clients machine.

Comment: @MathiasBak *"You can not just run Java from a script node."*  If by 'script node' you mean JavaScript, sure you can.  Something like `alert(java.lang.System.getProperty("java.version"))` should pop the info. on the Java version installed in the browser.

Comment: @AndrewThompson well OK explain how you can run *arbitrary Java functions that come from unknown places* from ordinary JavaScript in an ordinary browser.

Comment: @AndrewThompson does not work for me. can you link to a resource explaining the code? I get Uncaught ReferenceError: java is not defined.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I'd like to know too; I don't see how that'd be possible.

Comment: @MathiasBak Can you ask a question to that effect?

Comment: @AndrewThompson done. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8334987/running-java-code-form-script-node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [LiveConnect](http://jdk6.java.net/plugin2/liveconnect/) to enable bidirectional communication between Java and JavaScript within a page.

Answer (score 1):

You can only call interact with Java if it's running on a Java Applet.

If you need to interact with the clipboard in Javascript, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-clipboard-in-javascript) Stack Overflow question answers that for you.

Comment: is correct.  Apart from that you can execute it at server side using Ajax call and then update DOM accordingly.

Comment: @SidCool Sure. I was referring to client side interaction only (which seems to be what the parent poster was interested in).